# Convert cs file encoding

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding

I recently got asked to review a Visual Studio solution. One of the first things I did was run SourceMonitor on it. But when I tried to analyze it, I got an error that said SourceMonitor could not parse Unicode or UTF-encoded files. Is there a quick was to convert all of the .cs file in a solution to ASCII encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert anything:

From the [SourceMonitor page](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html):

> An option has been added to the
>   Options | General dialog to allow
>   parsing of source code files with
>   UTF-8 encoding. These files will parse
>   correctly as long as all characters in
>   the file are represented by 8 bit
>   codes.